# Drawing with turtle module and while loops in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this code to request an input: number of points on a star, then use the turtle module to draw each respective star. Each one is meant to be in a distinct location and have a distinct line and fill color. This code won't draw second and third stars, though it'll draw the first one fine. Also, the fill function only fills the "arms" of the star, not the body. I'm attaching some code and a screenshot of when I tried it with the three inputs: 5, 7, and 9.

```
from turtle import *

def start():
    """This function initializes the window and the turtle.
    Do not modify this function.
    """
    setup(564, 564)
    width(7)
    side_length = 60 # Also the radius of a circle enclosed by the star.
    penup()
    goto(0, -side_length) # Start at the bottom of the star.
    pendown()

def main():
    points = int(input('How many points would you like on your star? '))
    A = 360 / points
    B = 2 * A
    x = 0
    side_length = 60

    while x < points:
        color('blue', 'red')
        begin_fill()
        left(A)
        forward(side_length)
        right(B)
        forward(side_length)
        x += 1
        end_fill()

    penup()
    goto(2*side_length, 2*side_length)
    pendown()

    points = int(input('How many points would you like on your star? '))
    while x < points:
        color('green', 'yellow')
        begin_fill()
        left(A)
        forward(side_length)
        right(B)
        forward(side_length)
        x += 1
        end_fill()

    penup()
    goto(-2*side_length, 2*side_length)
    pendown()

    points = int(input('How many points would you like on your star? '))
    while x < points:
        color('orange', 'purple')
        begin_fill()
        left(A)
        forward(side_length)
        right(B)
        forward(side_length)
        x += 1
        end_fill()

# Do not change anything after this line.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
    main()
    done()
```

[image: This is the output of my code as drawn by the turtle module]

Comment: Do you reset `x = 0` after each while loop?

Comment: This did help a little bit. Now the program will draw all three stars, but not with a different number of points. However many points I give the first star is how all three will appear, though the program will trace the its lines the appropriate number of times.

Comment: You would also need to recalculate `A = 360 / points` and `B = 2 * A`.

Comment: Thank you, that does help a lot, though I'm still having small issues. I just found out that the diameter of these stars has to be 60pixels, though currently I have it set that each side has a length of 60pixels. I don't quite know how to change it. If you don't mind continuing to help, do you have any advice?

Comment: Would assume diameter of 60 would just be `side_length = 60/2`